# Count number of living firms efficiently

Tags: stata

I have a list of companies with **start** and **end** dates for each. I want to count the number of companies alive over time. I have the following code but it runs slowly on my large dataset. Is there a more efficient way to do this in Stata?

```
forvalues y = 1982/2012 {
    forvalues m = 1/12 {

    *display date("01-`m'-`y'","DMY")
    count if start_dt <= date("01-`m'-`y'","DMY") & date("01-`m'-`y'","DMY") <= end_dt

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the `inrange` function. In Stata, `Date` variables are just integers so you can easily operate on them.

```
forvalues y = 1982/2012 {

    forvalues m = 1/12 {

        local d = date("01-`m'-`y'","DMY")
        count if inrange(`d', start_dt, end_dt)

    }
}
```

This alone will save you a huge amount of time. For 50.000 observations (and made-up data):

```
. timer list 1
   1:      3.40 /        1 =       3.3980

. timer list 2
   2:     18.61 /        1 =      18.6130
```

*timer 1* is with `inrange`, *timer 2* is your original code. Results are in seconds. Run `help inrange` and `help timer` for details.

That said, maybe someone can suggest an overall better strategy.

Comment: Note that this way each distinct date is evaluated just once. With the original code it was being evaluated twice for every observation.

Comment: @NickCox I know that Stata functions (excluding `egen` functions) are not open source, but can you say what `inrange` is doing under the hood? I'm inclined to think that it also does a double evaluation but in compiled **C** language which makes it much faster. Would this be correct?

Comment: I was not alluding to `inrange()`, but the `date()` evaluation that is performed. The `inrange()` evaluation is necessarily performed separately for each observation. As you say, I can't comment on how  that is coded in Stata's internal C code, but a call to C code it presumably is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a firm identifier `firmid`, this is another way to think about the problem, but with a different data structure. Make sure you have a saved copy of your dataset before you do this.

```
expand 2 
bysort firmid : gen eitherdate = cond(_n == 1, start_dt, end_dt) 
by firmid : gen score = cond(_n == 1, 1, -1) 
sort eitherdate 
gen living = sum(score) 
by eitherdate : replace living = living[_N]
```

So,

1. We `expand` each observation to 2 and put both dates in a new variable, the start date in one observation and the end date in the other observation.
2. We assign a score that is 1 when a firm starts and -1 when it ends.
3. The number of firms is increased by 1 every time a firm starts and decreased by 1 every time one ends. We just need to sort by date and the number of firms is the cumulative sum of those scores. (EDIT: There is a fix for changes on the same date.)

This new data structure could be useful for other purposes.

There is a write-up at http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0068

EDIT:

Notes in response to @Roberto Ferrer (and anyone else who read this):

1. I fixed a bad bug, which made this too difficult to understand. Sorry about that.
2. The dates used here are just the dates at which firms start and end. There is no evident point in evaluating the number of firms at any other date as it would just be the same number as the previous date used. If you needed, however, to interpolate to a grid of dates, copying the previous count would be sufficient.
3. It is important not to confuse the Stata function `sum()` which returns the cumulative sum with any `egen` function. The impression that `egen`'s `total()` is an alternative here was a side-effect of my bug.

Comment: I haven't been able to read the article but let me see if I understand:
Your final result establishes the number of living firms not for all possible
dates (like in the loop), but for each date
in variable `eitherdate`. If the number is negative, then those are dying
firms. Is that correct? Why not use `egen, total()` in substitution for the 
last two lines? Is it because of speed issues?

Comment: I have added some notes in the answer.

Comment: Quite an elegant solution; very ingenious.